# Overwriting of variable in SqlDataReader while-loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, sqldatareader

I have read some threads that seem to be similar to this but can't find the fix for my issue, I've not used stack overflow much so pls bear with me

I have a while loop using an SqlDataReader which is pulling information from a DB and putting it into a List for Development Requests as below

```
public ListOfDevelopmentRequestsModel GetDevRequests(List<SelectListItem> evaluators)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.DevRequests.GetDevRequests, Conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ListOfDevelopmentRequestsModel ListOfDevRequests = new ListOfDevelopmentRequestsModel();
            Conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime requestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateCreated"].ToString());
                string requestorFirstName = reader["Staff First Name"].ToString();
                string requestorLastName = reader["Staff Last Name"].ToString();
                string requestorEmailAddress = reader["Staff Email"].ToString();
                string solutionName = reader["SolutionName"].ToString();
                string solutionDescription = reader["SoultionDescription"].ToString();
                string solutionElementName = reader["SolutionElementName"].ToString();
                string solutionElementDescription = reader["SolutionElementDescription"].ToString();
                string itemToChange = reader["ItemChange"].ToString();
                string changeDetails = reader["ChangeDetail"].ToString();

                List<SelectListItem> evaluatorList = new List<SelectListItem>(DisplayCurrentEvaluator(evaluators, evaluator));

                DevelopmentRequestModel DevRequest = new DevelopmentRequestModel
                {
                    RequestDate = requestDate,
                    RequestorName = $"{requestorFirstName} {requestorLastName}",
                    RequestorEmailAddress = requestorEmailAddress,
                    SolutionName = solutionName,
                    SolutionDescription = solutionDescription,
                    SolutionElementName = solutionElementName,
                    SolutionElementDescription = solutionElementDescription,
                    ItemToChange = itemToChange,
                    ChangeDetails = changeDetails,
                    AccordionHeading = $"{(changeID.PadLeft(4, '0'))} - {requestorFirstName} {requestorLastName} - {itemToChange}"
                };

                ListOfDevRequests.DevelopmentRequests.Add(DevRequest);
            }
            Conn.Close();

            return ListOfDevRequests;
        }
```

I also have a List for getting Evaluators of the requests

```
        public static List<SelectListItem> GetEvaluators()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> evaluators = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.DevRequests.GetEvaluators, Conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                evaluators.Add(
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = reader["Staff Name"].ToString(),
                        Value = reader["Staff Code"].ToString(),
                    });
            }
            Conn.Close();
            return evaluators;
        }
```

Finally I have a List that will pass the above Evaluators List in and the Evaluator that was pulled from the DB: `string evaluator = reader["Evaluator"].ToString();` and will set the default value of the select list based on whether the Evaluator name matches the  Text value, and set it as the selected select list item.

```
        public List<SelectListItem> DisplayCurrentEvaluator(List<SelectListItem> evaluators, string evaluator)
        {
            foreach (var item in evaluators)
            {
                if (item.Text == evaluator)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Selected = false;
                }
            }

            return evaluators;

        }
```

The issue is that the first item in the loop has the Evaluator "Bill" and "Bill" is selected, and works fine, however the second item in the loop is "John", and when it sets "John" to selected, it replaces "Bill" as the selected value in the first item with "John"

The code has ended up a mess as I have tried multiple different ways to fix but I'm stumped and would appreciate help.

Sorry if the post is formatted poorly to read, I can try to reformat and provide more information if requested.

Cheers

EDITED CODE:

GetDevRequests()

```
 public ListOfDevelopmentRequestsModel GetDevRequests(List<SelectListItem> evaluators)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.DevRequests.GetDevRequests, Conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ListOfDevelopmentRequestsModel ListOfDevRequests = new ListOfDevelopmentRequestsModel();
            Conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<SelectListItem> evaluatorList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string changeID = reader["ChangeID"].ToString();
                string evaluator = reader["Evaluator"].ToString();
                string status = reader["Status"].ToString();
                string priority = reader["Priority"].ToString();
                string eliteID = reader["RequestorID"].ToString();
                DateTime requestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateCreated"].ToString());
                string requestorFirstName = reader["Staff First Name"].ToString();
                string requestorLastName = reader["Staff Last Name"].ToString();
                string requestorEmailAddress = reader["Staff Email"].ToString();
                string solutionName = reader["SolutionName"].ToString();
                string solutionDescription = reader["SoultionDescription"].ToString();
                string solutionElementName = reader["SolutionElementName"].ToString();
                string solutionElementDescription = reader["SolutionElementDescription"].ToString();
                string itemToChange = reader["ItemChange"].ToString();
                string changeDetails = reader["ChangeDetail"].ToString();

                evaluatorList = DisplayCurrentEvaluator(evaluators, evaluator);

                DevelopmentRequestModel DevRequest = new DevelopmentRequestModel
                {
                    ChangeID = (changeID.PadLeft(4, '0')),
                    Evaluator = evaluator,
                    Evaluators = evaluatorList,
                    Status = status,
                    Priority = priority,
                    EliteID = eliteID,
                    RequestDate = requestDate,
                    RequestorName = $"{requestorFirstName} {requestorLastName}",
                    RequestorEmailAddress = requestorEmailAddress,
                    SolutionName = solutionName,
                    SolutionDescription = solutionDescription,
                    SolutionElementName = solutionElementName,
                    SolutionElementDescription = solutionElementDescription,
                    ItemToChange = itemToChange,
                    ChangeDetails = changeDetails,
                    AccordionHeading = $"{(changeID.PadLeft(4, '0'))} - {requestorFirstName} {requestorLastName} - {itemToChange}"
                };

                ListOfDevRequests.DevelopmentRequests.Add(DevRequest);
            }
            Conn.Close();

            return ListOfDevRequests;
        }
```

DisplayCurrentEvaluator()

```
        public List<SelectListItem> DisplayCurrentEvaluator(List<SelectListItem> selectListItems, string selectListDefaultItem)
        {
            foreach (var item in selectListItems)
            {
                item.Selected = item.Text == selectListDefaultItem;
            }

            return selectListItems;

        }
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to select multiple values (i.e. both Bill and John)? Then only set the matching ones to `true`, don't set non-matching to `false` (because "Bill" doesn't match "John").

Comment: @HansKeﬆing The intention is to select a default drop down value, to display the currently selected evaluator.

So essentially it should be a List that will contain all the Evaluators, but mark a single evaluator as selected. It does this by comparing the Names in the List to the returned 'Evaluator' value from the database and marking one `selected = true`. I hope that makes a little more sense, sorry



- edit: pressed enter too soon, adding more to reply

Comment: Say the reader returns two records. You are now rewriting the evaluator list twice, letting the last one win. Say the first record has evaluator Bill and the second one John. What evaluators do you want checked, Bill, John or both?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing The evaluator list would be different for each record so I assume  youd write to it the first time, this is the list that each record now uses, then each time you create a model you assign the evaluator list to that model with the selected item, it then moves onto the next list and does it again.
If the first record has evaluator Bill, then Bill should be the evaluator for just that one. And if the second record has John as the evaluator it'd be record 1 - Bill, record 2 - John etc etc. Unless another future record has Bill as an evaluator also, then it would be records 1 & 7 etc

Comment: I'm assuming my issue is coming from not having worked with SqlDataReader and while loops and not understanding how the data flows through it. Sorry for the inexperience.

Comment: It's not because of the SqlDataReader but details about references - see my edit. And everyone had to learn sometime :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
List<SelectListItem> evaluatorList = new List<SelectListItem>(DisplayCurrentEvaluator(evaluators, evaluator));
```

First, this can also be written as

```
List<SelectListItem> evaluatorList = DisplayCurrentEvaluator(evaluators, evaluator);
```

Your `DisplayCurrentEvaluator` already returns a correct list, so there is no need to copy it into a new one.

But this is a minor point as you don't *use* that evaluatorList as far as I can see. In every iteration of that while-loop you are creating a new one (which probably isn't what you want) and then you forget about it. I also don't see where `evaluator` is set, but that is probably in code you didn't show.

So you will need to generate this list once, outside the loop and keep it (probably in a class-level field or property).

And an extra tip, that DisplayCurrentEvaluator method can also be written as

```
public List<SelectListItem> DisplayCurrentEvaluator(List<SelectListItem> evaluators, string evaluator)
{
    foreach (var item in evaluators)
    {
        item.Selected = item.Text == evaluator;
    }

    return evaluators;
}
```

**EDIT** after code was shown that set `evaluator` and used the resulting `evaluatorList`

Your DisplayCurrentEvaluator updates the original evaluators list and returns it. This effectively results in every evaluatorList pointing to the same list, where the last update wins. So make sure you return a new list.

```
public List<SelectListItem> DisplayCurrentEvaluator(List<SelectListItem> evaluators, string evaluator)
{
    var result = new List<SelectListItem>(evaluators.Count);

    foreach (var item in evaluators)
    {
        result.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Text, Value = item.Value, Selected= item.Text == evaluator};      
    }

    return result;
}
```

Additionally, declare the evaluatorList (only) inside of the loop.

```
 var evaluatorList = DisplayCurrentEvaluator(evaluators, evaluator);
```

Comment: Hi,

This line: `List<SelectListItem> evaluatorList = DisplayCurrentEvaluator(evaluators, evaluator);` is actually how I'd wrote it in my first iteration, but subsequent attempts to fix the functionality muddied it a bit.

I will stop copying the list into a new one too..

In regards to evaluator not being set, you're correct, I removed some of the code for the post but accidentally removed that, however its set similarly to the rest.

I thought I had set evaluatorList but evidentally in this code I have not, I will comb back through and see if your suggestions help fix. Thanks!!

Comment: I am going to edit my original post, I believe your suggestions actually bring my code quite close to my original iteration of it before I tried everything I could think of to fix it, however it seems like the same issue that each iteration is overwriting the old one. I have pasted the entire function this time also.